# JS update URL with GET request parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, parameters, query-string

I need to submit GET request and add a parameters from this request to the end of the URL. **Without page refreshing** or **HTML5 history API**.

Is it possible?

For example:

Original URL:

```
http://site.ch/page
```

After GET request:

```
http://site.ch/page?param_1=1&param_2=2
```

Comment: Just do an ajax call to url + parameters? Or what are you trying to do.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do, but the only other way I know of (other than History API) to change URL is setting `window.location` but it most certainly reloads the page unless you only change hash part of the URL. So in your situation you may have something like `http://site.ch/page#param_1=1&param_2=2`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: @Shilly i need to dynamicly update URL with new AJAX parameters without page refresh or history api

Comment: As Olga says, use the hash to change the parameters that you got from your GET request into the url without changing the history. window.location.hash = ???

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'm aware of is to use the fragment part of the URL.